# Eps file not open in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu

I recently updated ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04.Everything fine ok but can't able to open any .eps file with the default document viewer document.I also tried other software but till now now can't resolve my problem.

Comment: Document Viewer, LibreOffice Draw, Inkscape, and GIMP can all open .eps files in Ubuntu 18.04. What happens when you try to open this file: [circle.eps](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/eps/circle.eps)?

Comment: And circle.eps opens just fine in gwenview and okular in Kubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try Gimp for opening "eps" files.

Comment: i have tried ....not opening...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/890526)

Comment: @MrShunz On the contrary it does provide an answer to the question. My GIMP can open .eps files.

Comment: @karel usually, "try this/try that" oneliners belongs to comments. And as Wang commented, GIMP doesn't work either.

Comment: OK, I'll try to ask for more information about it in the comments.